Debugger/Programmer Invalid Target Device
I use a PicKit5 to program a PIC24EP128MC202 using MPLAB x IDE v6.20 with XC16 Compiler, I recently fixed some memory model issues and I ran into this problem where "Invalid Target Device"
Output file :
Connecting to MPLAB PICkit 5

Currently loaded versions:
Application version...........02.01.83
Boot version..................00.00.10
PCB version...................2
Script version................00.07.47
Script build number...........974b928e70
Tool pack version ............2.5.391
PICkit 5 is supplying power to the target (3.25 volts).
Target Device ID (0x0) is an Invalid Device ID. Please check your connections to the Target Device.

Calculating memory ranges for operation...

Erasing...

The following memory area(s) will be programmed:
program memory: start address = 0x0, end address = 0x7ff
configuration memory

 [ Pgm ] at 0x0, expected 0x00040200, got 0x00000000.
Programming did not complete.


Diagram :

Pins layout :

User guide -> PICKIT5
DATA SHEET PIC24EP128MC202(download only on official website)
Solutions?

I have no enemies - Hi, I work with other MCUs, but based on the message: "Target Device ID (0x0) is an Invalid Device ID. Please check your connections to the Target Device.", how have you confirmed that the hardware is OK? I recommend you edit your question and add your schematic, photos of your actual hardware and show your analysis, test results & measurements that make you believe the hardware should be working. || Have you got a known-working PIC24 board (e.g. a Microchip development board) to allow you to check your processes, before you introduce the "unknown" of your own hardware?

No, I've had nobody to introduce me to electronics. Neither knew about what a PIC24 board is. I'm not sure if there has to be any measurements for the hardware, the chance of the PIC to be faulty can be an option but I have 2 of them and tested on the other, they are brand new. Hard reset the laptop, checked the connections again on the wires, it had no effect.

Electronics might be one of the hardest things for me to get the grasp on since information is vastly outdated and some constant updates on software and some on hardware make it hard to keep track. I can't find someone to introduce me to this with all the knowledge lacking in both physics and programing (embedded is different). I was trying to learn assembly but the MPLAB compiler wouldn't want to since it was outdated(more than half of the commands were unrecognizable), I didn't find solutions so I try to stick with C.

@SamGibson as for the debugger, it programs well, I used it on a much simpler MCU like PIC10F200.

I have no enemies - Thanks for the update. However there are some problems: (a) You included material copied / adapted from elsewhere, without the required source reference. Breaking that rule means the question is eligible for deletion. To avoid that, please ASAP edit the question and add the name(s) & link(s) (URL) of the source(s) of the copied images. (If you haven't yet read the [tour] & [help], please do that, as they contain the main site rules.) (b) You didn't include a schematic nor photos of the hardware as I asked, so it's unrealistic for me to advise further :(

@SamGibson let me know if there is still anything else breaking the rules in the post as 2nd checks never do harm.

I have no enemies - Thanks for adding 2 links & a schematic. (a) I eventually found the device pinout which you copied, on page 5 in the PIC24 family datasheet which was linked from one of the added links. That (if I'm correct about the source) is the link you should give. Linking to a webpage which doesn't itself contain the copied material, is inadequate and doesn't comply with the referencing rule.

(continued) (b) Also, clicking the PICkit5 user guide link you gave, doesn't show the copied image, so there must be more to it than just that link (perhaps it's necessary to click somewhere on that page? But you didn't say so...). (c) If that schematic is correct i.e. if you are making only those connections to a bare IC (and not to some kind of dev board which has additional components on it) then there are several issues. However I'm still waiting for the photo of your actual hardware to confirm my suspicions, so I avoid wasting time on guesses.

@SamGibson I hope my update suffices your expectations now

Programming failures are the one of the most frustrating issues to debug in electronics. It's usually technically trivial, but can have a great number of causes, such as bad wiring (inc. loose connection), incorrect pinout, bad power supply (inc. disabled rails), marginal logic level, internal vs. external MCU clock source, bad driver/software, finally bad hardware. If you have an oscilloscope or logic analyzer, probing the voltages and signals between the MCU and the programmer would be your first step of investigation. Can you see any handshakes from the programmer? Does the MCU reply?

@比尔盖子 There are handshakes from the programmer, I'm not sure how I should detect a reply from the MCU. The connections are checkd, the supply is made by the programmer itself, sadly I don't own an oscilloscope or logic analyzer to check more details.

@Ihavenoenemies When I said "see handshakes", I meant "seeing the electrical signals of the handshake via an oscilloscope or logic analyzer" - you really need to check the problem physically. Unfortunately, troubleshooting this problem without any test equipment is going to be very, very hard. For a low-cost solution, perhaps you build a quick-and-dirty analyzer using some microcontroller development boards, such as the EZ-USB FX2LP.
